# Is there an option to move data directly to Snowflake without going through S3 and other cloud storage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We choosed Snowflake as our DWH and we would like to connect different data sources like (Salesforce, Hubspot and Zendesk).

Is there a way to extract data from these sources and store them in Snowflake in a staging schema without having to store the data in cloud storage like S3 then reading the data into Snowflake?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the connectors Snowflake provide (odbc, jdbc, python, etc) and any tool that can use one of these connectors. However they wont perform well compared to the COPY INTO approach that is optimised for bulk loading.

There are ETL tools, such as Matillion, that use the stage/copy into approach but do it in the background so that it appears that you are loading directly into Snowflake.